# next and previous year month and day for archive page

Tags: archives, calendar, previous, next

is there php code for next and previous year,month,day link in archive page
i just need something like that

```
<-previous [year] next->
<-previous [month] next->
<-previous [day] next->
```

im creating a calendar and need those .

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Like your honesty. Just an idea, why don't you use the build in calendar widget as base for yours

Answer (score -1):

thank u all 
i just did a simple code to get what i want

```
<?php 
$prevyear = date('2150') - 0001;
$nextyear = date('2150') + 0001;
$prevmonth = date('01') - 01;
$nextmonth = date('01') + 01;
echo echo get_year_link($prevyear)."<br />".get_year_link($nextyear)."<br />".get_year_link($prevmonth)."<br />".get_year_link($nextmonth)."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain why is this good solution?

Comment: It's not a good solution. This assumes there always will be post for every month going backwards and forever in time until infinity.